# Alamofire Passing Parameter With following type

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

[image]

How to send this data as parameter in alamofire request as parameter?

What I'm doing is:

[image]

Requesting Service:

[image]

I'm getting this:

[image]

I Supposed to get this by sending following way of data:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why I had got negative vote in this question.

Comment: Here is the answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58173318/6165231](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58173318/6165231) he made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at the api you're using: The api expects for the data value to be a string and not an object.
You'll need to do something like this: But this can be refactored to be much cleaner, this is just to explain whats going on.

Create data params:

```
let data: Parameters = [
    "username": "\(textFieldUserName.text!)",
    "pass": "\(textFieldPassword.text!)"
]
```

then convert it to a string: below is a quick search to convert json to string, but you'll need to double check that, as I took the first answer.

```
let string = stringify(json: data, prettyPrinted: false)

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "data": string
]
```

and in the request set the encoding to: `encoding: URLEncoding.default`

```
Alamofire.request(
        loginURL,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: URLEncoding.default,
        headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if responseData.result.value != nil {
                //do something with data
    }
}

func stringify(json: Any, prettyPrinted: Bool = false) -> String {
    var options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []
    if prettyPrinted {
        options = JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted
    }

    do {
      let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: options)
      if let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
          return string
      }
    } catch {
          print(error)
    }
    return ""
}
```

I would also try to avoid force unwrapping the textfield.text properties, unless you're validating their values somewhere else before hand
and since the api call is http, you also need to enabled that in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Alamofire.request` function with definition contains `parameters: Parameters` one. Like below.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:3030/", headers: [ACCESS_TOKEN:token, "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  ],
        parameters:["formData2" : formblabla, "formData1" : formblabla],
        encoding: .URL).response(completionHandler: {
            (request, response, data, error) in
        })
```

And there is the another fix to do for your question:

You set the your data in `postman` wrongly

The format is `{ "username": "blabla", "pass": "xxx" }` is completely wrong.

Search for documenation of post data for `Postman`

You've to put all of the attributes separately as `Key-Value pair.`

Comment: parameter like `["formData2" : formblabla, "formData1" : formblabla]` is not working.

Comment: can you describe your parameters like this `let parameters: Parameters = [
        "test": "123"
        ]`

Comment: yes i did the same, and it require those curly brace.

Comment: did you use `response` or `responseJSON`for the getting response block? Can you try `responseJSON` if you've not use it.

Comment: responseJSON, what i'm using there.

Comment: Updated the question. you can see now.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra I think I solve your problem, check my updated answer, you send your data wrongly in Postman. try it with key-pair and get result, then compare it with your response on Alamofire.

Comment: there is a key `data`

Comment: use www-form-urlencoded and set each value for each key for example a value for username and other value for pass key

Comment: I tried so many thing, but I failed every time. And above code is backdated I found that too.

Comment: I guess its older versions of the Alamofire, there are something to change for example encoding and method type. You can found out in github.com/Alamofire

Comment: Thanks though, I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary

```
let parameters = ["username": "xxxxx", "pass":"xxx"]

 Alamofire.request(YOURURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:nil ).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let result = response.result.value
            let json = result as Dictionary
            print(json)
        case .failure(let error):
            let responseString = String(data: response.data, encoding:.utf8)
        }
```

Comment: where is the parameter??

Comment: Sorry you can check now

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: it is not providing the actual data.