# Alamofire parameter with multiple values in one Key

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

How to send parameter as alamofire parameter for the following data?

`data : {"username":"username","password":"password"}`

I want to achieve following through alamofire paramter, but I failed to achieve this.

what I'm doing is:

`let parameter: Parameters = ["data": ["username": "\(textFieldUserName.text!)", "pass": "\(textFieldPassword.text!)"]]`

`Alamofire.request(loginUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameter,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in`

but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more your question?

Comment: @summerfinn3 I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and where you are having issues?  This looks like a pretty standard alamofire request: Here is their official documentation: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at the api you're using: The api expects for the data value to be a string and not an object.
You'll need to do something like this: But this can be refactored to be much cleaner, this is just to explain whats going on.

Create data params:

```
let data: Parameters = [
    "username": "\(textFieldUserName.text!)",
    "pass": "\(textFieldPassword.text!)"
]
```

then convert it to a string: below is a quick search to convert json to string, but you'll need to double check that, as I took the first answer.

```
let string = stringify(json: data, prettyPrinted: false)

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "data": string
]
```

and in the request set the encoding to: `encoding: URLEncoding.default`

```
Alamofire.request(
        loginURL,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: URLEncoding.default,
        headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if responseData.result.value != nil {
                //do something with data
    }
}

func stringify(json: Any, prettyPrinted: Bool = false) -> String {
    var options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []
    if prettyPrinted {
        options = JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted
    }

    do {
      let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: options)
      if let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
          return string
      }
    } catch {
          print(error)
    }
    return ""
}
```

I would also try to avoid force unwrapping the textfield.text properties, unless you're validating their values somewhere else before hand
and since the api call is http, you also need to enabled that in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: but here `data` is the key. an I failed to understand this curly brace there.

Comment: I did it same like:
`let parameter: Parameters = ["data": ["username": "\(textFieldUserName.text!)", "pass": "\(textFieldPassword.text!)"]]` but I failed to bring those form of data. It is sending with body and I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: I did it, though it is not showing the result as postman showing.